# memset VS zeroing through a simple loop "for"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Can you please tell me what this weirdness is?

Here's some simple code: VS2019, x64, release. Windows 10.

0. Create a vector, fill it with random values.
1. I create a pointer and allocate memory through malloc, I do not initialize the memory and through a loop I copy data from the vector to the allocated memory.
2. Create a pointer and allocate memory via malloc, initialize the allocated memory 0 via Memset and through a loop  copy the data from the vector to the allocated memory.
3. Create a pointer and allocate memory via malloc, initialize allocated memory 1 via Memset and through a loop copy data from the vector to the allocated memory.
4. Create a pointer and allocate memory through malloc, initialize the allocated memory 0 through a loop and through a cycle copy the data from the vector to the allocated memory.
5. Create a pointer and allocate memory through malloc, initialize allocated memory 1 through a loop and through a loop copy data from the vector to the allocated memory.

And now I measure the time of each section from 1 to 5:

```
1: 31 ms
2: 33 ms
3: 33 ms
4: 32 ms
5: 12 ms
```

That is, all variants of filling the memory, except for item 5, have the same time and only item 5 - where the memory is initialized through a cycle and by "1" - only this option is more than twice as fast. Why is that ??

**PS: Changing the order of variants does not affect the result! That is, I rearranged the 5th cycle to the very beginning - the result is the same.**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    size_t num = 9999999;

    //-----------------Filling a vector random values--------

    std::vector<size_t>my_vector_rand;
    my_vector_rand.resize(num);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_vector_rand[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int clock1;
    int clock2;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter1 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter1[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_without_all:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter1[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter2 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset.

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter2[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter3 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset.

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter3[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter4 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle.

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter4[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter5 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle.

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter5[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Disassembled messet and loop code:

```
    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    00007FF798DC5A36  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
    00007FF798DC5A3A  shl         rax,3  
    00007FF798DC5A3E  mov         r8,rax  
    00007FF798DC5A41  xor         edx,edx  
    00007FF798DC5A43  mov         rcx,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter2]  
    00007FF798DC5A4A  call        memset (07FF798DC1460h)  
    
    
    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    00007FF798DC5B80  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
    00007FF798DC5B84  shl         rax,3  
    00007FF798DC5B88  mov         r8,rax  
    00007FF798DC5B8B  mov         edx,1  
    00007FF798DC5B90  mov         rcx,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter3]  
    00007FF798DC5B97  call        memset (07FF798DC1460h)  
    



    
           for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
00007FF798DC5CCD  mov         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],0  
00007FF798DC5CD8  jmp         main+46Bh (07FF798DC5CEBh)  
00007FF798DC5CDA  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+1A8h]  
00007FF798DC5CE1  inc         rax  
00007FF798DC5CE4  mov         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],rax  
00007FF798DC5CEB  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
00007FF798DC5CEF  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],rax  
00007FF798DC5CF6  jae         main+490h (07FF798DC5D10h)  
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
00007FF798DC5CF8  mov         rax,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter4]  
00007FF798DC5CFF  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+1A8h]  
00007FF798DC5D06  mov         qword ptr [rax+rcx*8],0  
    }
    
    



    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
00007FF798DC5E41  mov         qword ptr [rbp+208h],0  
00007FF798DC5E4C  jmp         main+5DFh (07FF798DC5E5Fh)  
00007FF798DC5E4E  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+208h]  
00007FF798DC5E55  inc         rax  
00007FF798DC5E58  mov         qword ptr [rbp+208h],rax  
00007FF798DC5E5F  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
00007FF798DC5E63  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+208h],rax  
00007FF798DC5E6A  jae         main+604h (07FF798DC5E84h)  
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
00007FF798DC5E6C  mov         rax,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter5]  
00007FF798DC5E73  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+208h]  
00007FF798DC5E7A  mov         qword ptr [rax+rcx*8],1  
    }
```

**ADDITION:**

If after each memset that fills the allocated memory 1 or 0.

And if after the loop that fills the allocated memory 0 - add these lines:

```
size_t summ_memset_0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    summ_memset_0 = summ_memset_0 + my_sizet_pionter2[i];
}
std::cout << summ_memset_0 << std::endl;
```

But now the execution time for all options except the 1st, for which the memory was not initialized - the execution time becomes the same:

1: 31 ms

2: 11 ms

3: 12 ms

4: 13 ms

5: 12 ms

Probably the compiler has optimized the code after all, and seems to have thrown out the initialization of the allocated memory through memset and through a loop. But for some reason left the initialization of the allocated memory through the "1" loop.

Here's the final code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{

    size_t num = 9999999;


    //-----------------Filling a vector random values--------

    std::vector<size_t>my_vector_rand;
    my_vector_rand.resize(num);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_vector_rand[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    int clock1;
    int clock2;




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter1 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter1[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_without_all:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter1[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter2 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. it didn't help.


    size_t summ_memset_0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_memset_0 = summ_memset_0 + my_sizet_pionter2[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_memset_0 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.



    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter2[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter3 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. it didn't help.



    size_t summ_memset_1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_memset_1 = summ_memset_1 + my_sizet_pionter3[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_memset_1 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.



    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter3[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter4 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle. it didn't help.



    size_t summ_loop_0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_loop_0 = summ_loop_0 + my_sizet_pionter4[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_loop_0 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.




    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter4[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------





    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter5 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle.


    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter5[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Allan Wind, code is absolutely 100% compileable. This code won't compile for you?

Comment: Yes, but it's not minimal... if you are asking why 1 and 5 are different, then eliminate 2 through 4.  memcpy has an overhead, so 1 vs num might be 20ms, you might also return before write is complete I.e. memory barrier.

Comment: @AllanWind `[mre]` expands to [mre]. Here's [a list of other useful shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @user4581301 sweet, thanks.

Comment: @Allan Wind, Why memcpy is it 2.5 times faster in the fifth option ?? Where has your memory barrier gone?

Comment: @AllanWind No - the code blocks are equivalent. The `num * sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(size_t)` (on its own) are the same in all cases.

Comment: Also, I can 'semi' reproduce on my Windows 10 + MSVC system. The numbers are different but (5) is consistently significantly faster than the other 4. Even when I move that block into a different place (testing if its caching).

Comment: Also doesn't work as expected on Linux so I am going to tag it VS2019

Comment: @jxh, Why should the fifth call of malloc behave differently and what do you mean by this?

Comment: Allocators can take memory from different places as it is running. I was thinking perhaps you were facing a NUMA issue. But Adrian Mole says he already tested for that.

Comment: It could be that setting to 1 actually does make the memory hot in cache, but setting to 0 does not. Can you check to see what the setting to 0 code is actually doing?

Comment: @jxh, do you mean look at the disassembled code?

Comment: Loop. It is called "loop". A cycle is something else.

Comment: The same software configuration: VS2019, x64, release, Windows 10. It takes exactly 59 ms for each and every, including 5th. CPU - AMD Ryzen 3950X, this could matter. What's your CPU?

Comment: Additionally, C++11 introduced the [Chrono API](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/), it would be more precise to use it, GetTickCount or  QueryPerformanceCounter instead of clock().

Comment: Did you consider the fact that by 5th test the CPU could get my_vector_rand cached "closer"? Would the situation change if you run it as 2nd test, not 5th?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I tried that (see my earlier comment).

Comment: @Damir Tenishev, tested on Core i-5 and core i-7.

Comment: So, now you know that this is CPU-specific.

Comment: @Damir Tenishev, It is very strange.

Comment: Now you have to profile the code to see if you can identify a hot instruction

Comment: FYI, `memset` works on bytes (`uint8_t`).  Using `memset` to set an array to 1 may not perform as expected.  If your array is `uint16_t`, then in hex, your array values will be 0x0101` instead of `0x0001`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows with GCC. I repeat each step 100 times for better precision. With '-O2' it seems step 5 takes a little longer (~20%) than the others which are approximately equal. With '-O3' all steps take approximately the same time. CPU is i5-9600K. With repeated runs there are occasional outliers so it is difficult to say anything conclusive. Performance measurements on top of Windows is inherently uncertain.

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(size_t)`?  This may be a factor, for example when the processor's word size is 32-bits, but the processor's address range is 64-bits (size_t).

Comment: You should move the memory allocations outside of the benchmarking; heck, perform all the allocations at the start, before the copying.  The `malloc` and `new` functions are not guaranteed to have the same performance on each call.

Comment: Linux, gcc 10.3, -O2: versions with 1 are twice as fast as versions with 0. The difference I noticed in assembly is that versions with 0 are compiled to use a single `calloc()` call, while memset_one uses a single `memset()` call and cycle_one uses `mov 1` and `jne`.

Comment: I don't think [tag:visual-c++-2009] applies here, it may be wrong by a decade ?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, What for ? Why move the memory allocation to the beginning? What does this affect ??

Comment: @Ben Voigt , where does the VS2009?

Comment: @Optimus1: The tags at the bottom of your question (you picked them before submitting the question to the site).  Right above the "Share Edit Follow" links

Comment: @Ben Voigt, now I see. But I didn't put the tag VS2009 - someone else put it.

Comment: Optimus1: Oh you're right, Allan did.   @AllanWind can you explain why you added VC++ 2009 tag and not 2019 tag?

Comment: Moving the memory allocation before any of the assignments or copies, moves the variable time outside of the benchmarking.  Your measurements should be more consistent.

Comment: @jxh, please tell me - what does profile mean?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, measurements absolutely consistent.

Comment: There is also something strange influencing the results on gcc by failure to call `srand()` before using `rand()`. Without `srand()` the output of every one is `7ms`. (with `-O0` and with `srand()` it's `27ms` and adding `-Ofast` (`/Ox` on VS)) it jumps to `63ms`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019

Comment: The only thing I *don’t* see in the disassembly is the very code whose execution time differ. Is it actually the same for all 5 items?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/vtune-profiler.html

Comment: I am curious why you have a loop to call `memcpy` one element at a time, instead of a single call to `memcpy`.

Comment: @numzero, it also seemed strange to me, but VS 2019 showed just such a disassembler code.

Comment: @jxh, because such a condition - the elements come sequentially in parts of size - size_t.

Comment: @jxh, if interested, read the "addition" in my main post. It looks like the matter was in the compiler and its code optimization.